# Specifying different subclass implementations in CDI

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I have two classes, A and B, which need to use a service.  There are two services, S1 and S2.  S2 extends S1.  I wish to inject S1 into class A and S2 into class B.  How can I accomplish this in CDI?

```
public class S1 {}
public class S2 extends S1 {}

public class A {
    @Inject S1 service;  //Ambigious?  Could be S1 or S2?
}

public class B {
    @Inject S2 service;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`@Typed`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.2/javax/enterprise/inject/Typed.html) annotation enables [restricting bean types](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#restricting_bean_types) so that you can write:

```
public class S1 {}

@Typed(S2.class)
public class S2 extends S1 {}

public class A {
    @Inject S1 service;
}

public class B {
    @Inject S2 service;
}
```

In your deployment, [beans types](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_types) of the bean class `S2` will be restricted to `S2` and `Object` so that there will only one bean whose bean types contain type `S1` and the ambiguous resolution will be resolved.

Note that the `@Typed` annotation is available since CDI 1.0.

You could rely on qualifiers as well though it is preferable to use qualifiers for *functional* semantic.