# Ambiguous dependency warning with subclass implementation using @Typed in CDI

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cdi, weld

Here, one class is a subclass of the other.  Hence, the [@Typed](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.2/javax/enterprise/inject/Typed.html) annotation is used to prevent @Inject ambiguity.

```
@Dependent
public class UserScope extends Scope {}

@Dependent
@Typed(UserScopeAllowIdEquals.class) // Restrict bean type.
public class UserScopeAllowIdEquals extends UserScope {}
```

The following usage causes an inspection warning in Intellij:

```
public class A {
    @Inject UserScope userScope;
}
```

> Ambiguous dependency: there are multiple beans that match the
>   injection point

However, the application compiles and runs, the container not treating it as a definition error. Is there a problem with the way it's written?  I suspect not, if [this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29073156/984932) is correct, to indicate that there will only be one bean whose bean types contain the superclass.

NOTE: The following usage, as expected, does not cause an Intellij inspection warning.

```
public class B {
    @Inject UserScopeAllowIdEquals usaie;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on CDI, as long as there is more than one implementation of a bean, then the `@Default` qualifier no longer applies.

To go about this, you need to explicitly tell CDI which bean among your definitions, is the default bean.

```
@Dependent
@Default
public class UserScope extends Scope {}

@Dependent
@Typed(UserScopeAllowIdEquals.class) // Restrict bean type.
public class UserScopeAllowIdEquals extends UserScope {}
```

So when you do inject a `Scope` bean, without any qualifier, then the bean which has been explicitly specified to be the default will be selected:

```
@Inject
private Scope scopeBean; // The @Default annotated, if any of a Scope implementation is used.
```

Comment: After adding the `Default` qualifier to `UserScope` I'm still receiving the "Ambiguous dependency" warning where I inject `UserScope`.  To avoid confusion fyi Scope base class is abstract and so one would never inject `Scope`.

Comment: @PatrickGarner you actually need to inject the abstract class, not the concrete implementation

Comment: I need to inject a RoleScope, PermissionScope, AcademicYearScope, TransitionLogScope, etc., one scope type per database table.  All of these extend Scope.  UserScopeAllowIdEquals is the only oddball in the bunch, extending UserScope instead of Scope.

Comment: Am sure the reason why you extend ```Scope``` is because all these different scopes provide a uniform interface for verification of access-permissions, e.g. ```Scope.hasScope(...)```, so that the usage is quite transparent to the api user. In essence, based on the scenario you may be trying to arrive at, i would let my api users do something like  this: ```@Inject @ScopeContext(PERMISSION) Scope scope; @Inject @ScopeContext(ACADEMIC_YEAR) Scope scope``` etc

Comment: None of the injections caused a problem except where I injected `UserScope` after having extended it, so it seemed like a simpler approach to add the `@Typed` annotation to `UserScopeAllowIdEquals`, and that worked because, I think, in accordance with [the CDI spec. section 5.2.2, "Unsatisfied and ambiguous dependencies"](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#unsatisfied_and_ambig_dependencies) the ambiguous dependency became resolvable by the container.  So although it's ambiguous, it is resolvable, and it seems to me that the IDE should not give the warning.