# Getting Ambiguous dependency warning when creating Producer method

Tags: java, azure, kotlin

I've created a producer method to handle my authentication to Azure using Managed Identities. My application uses multiple Azure services, so I thought this might be the best way to just have one producer method for the authentication of all my Azure services.

My producer method looks like this:

```
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential
import com.azure.identity.ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder
import io.quarkus.arc.properties.IfBuildProperty
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces

@ApplicationScoped
class AzureManagedIdentity(
    private val azureManagedIdentityConfig: AzureManagedIdentityConfig,
) {
    @Produces
    fun managedIdToken(): TokenCredential = ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder()
        .clientId(azureManagedIdentityConfig.clientId())
        .build()
}
```

This seems to work, but I'm getting the following warning in my IDE: "Ambiguous dependency: there are multiple beans that match the injection point".

I'm using the TokenCredential (e.g. way of authenticating) like this:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential

@ApplicationScoped
class ServiceBusCaptureRequestPublisher(
    private val tokenCredential: TokenCredential,
    ) {
    // Logic
}
```

I searched the interwebs and found something about the code not knowing which TokenCredential needs to be used, or something like it. Now I also found something about Qualifiers, and the @Named annotation, but I'm a bit at a loss here.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Have you gone through this similar SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580395/ambiguous-dependency-warning-with-subclass-implementation-using-typed-in-cdi

Answer (score 1):

- Have you gone through the [Bean types](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_types) in your deployment. Which will help you in resolving Ambitious Resolution.
- [@Typed](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.2/javax/enterprise/inject/Typed.html) annotation is available since CDI 1.0
- You could rely on qualifiers as well though it is preferable to use qualifiers for *functional* semantic.
- Also check these [restricting bean types](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#restricting_bean_types).